# Strsep and iCalendar parsing in C

Tags: c, icalendar

I'm having trouble parsing a simple iCalendar file in C.

```
char * description, * identifier, *tofree;
tofree = description = strdup(string);
identifier = strsep(&description, ":");
printf("{%s}\n", identifier);
printf("[%s]\n", description);
free(tofree);
```

string would be the line I just read from the file, such as:
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
When I run this program, I get the following output:

```
{BEGIN}
]VCALENDAR
```

Can someone please help me determine what's causing this issue? The output should show "[VCALENDAR]" and I'm not sure why this is occurring.

Comment: Code seems fine to me , there is nothing here which seems wrong.

Comment: If you really would like to do a good program, consider to use `bison` and corresponding grammar description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your input data ends with a carriage return, `\r`.  Your code outputs:

```
[VCALENDAR\r]\n
```

and the carriage return places the cursor at the start of the line so the `]` overwrites your `[`.

It's probably best to remove the line ending before scanning; failing that, include `\r` and `\n` in the delimiters provided to `strsep()`, but you'd have to use `strsep()` a second time to get the `VCALENDAR` token.

Comment: Wow such a minute non-noticeable mistake caught . hats off :)

Comment: It's a "been there, done that" situation.  Having seen it once, it isn't hard to spot.  I often print `printf("Description: [%s]\n", description);` in such circumstances, and the output might appear to be `]escription: [VCALENDAR`, which gives a better indication of what's going on, perhaps.

Comment: @J Baba: another "learning" could be to include the input in the minimal example to avoid the "input is not as expected"-situations.